# Est-ce que qualité veux dire quelque chose de bien?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais

Ce matin j'ai étudié le français avec Babbel et j'ai traduit cette phrase:

> Curiosity is a good quality

Et la traduction est:

> La curiosité est une qualité

Je pensais que la définition de qualité devrait être quelque chose de bien que quelqu'un possède. Mais la définition du [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/qualit%C3%A9/65477) ne semble pas très claire pour moi, parce qu'il me semble que cela peut référer à quelque chose de positif ou à quelque chose de positif ou négatif.

Est-il normal d'utiliser qualité quand on veux dire quelque chose positif sur quelqu'un ? Devrais-je dire qu'il est une bonne qualité ?

P.S. I wrote in French to practice my skills, but if something is not clear I can write everything again in English. Answers are welcome in both languages.

Comment: Ici, le sens de "qualité" est l'opposé de celui de "défaut". Les qualités et les défauts de quelqu'un.

Comment: I’m impressed w/Babbel for recognizing that the French meaning of “qualité” in this context is positive/not neutral & doesn’t need the “bonne” even tho it's needed with the neutral “quality” in English. (It would be interesting to see if it'd be smart enough to translate “bad quality” in this context directly as "défaut" & not “mauvaise qualité.”) (It would also be interesting to see how it would translate “Curiosity is a virtue,” ‘cause that’s the best way I see to say “good quality” in one word in English, although “virtue” might be taking it a bit too far since it’s not one of the “Big 7”!)

Comment: En France, "La curiosité est un vilain défaut !", on le dit aux enfants qui par curiosité naturelle explorent les objets personnels de tout le monde. Ce n'est pas le cas de la curiosité du chercheur, mais pour lui, ce n'est pas une qualité, mais une nécessité.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused by the English sentence instead (but a similar situation exists in French language as I am going to highlight it later on):

> Curiosity is a good quality

In French, we can also say: *La curiosité est une bonne qualité*. The adjective *bonne* here reinforces the positive meaning of *qualité* (in the this context, *qualité* means good side). Note that you can also understand it (always in this context) as a charateristic/feautre.

But the meaning of *qualité* may change depending on the context:

1. *qualité*  may be the synonym of good side/good point/advantage (the opposite of flaw/drawback) such as in:

   - *Au cours de l'entretien, on m'a demandé de citer mes principaux défauts et mes principales **qualités*** : During the interiew, I have been asked  to list my main drawbacks and advantages.
2. *qualité* may also mean quality, such as in:

   - *J'ai acheté des légumes verts de **mauvaise qualité***: I have bought low quality green vegetables
   - *Pour mon anniversaire, il m'a offert un parfum de haute **qualité***: For my birthday, he  gave me a high quality perfume.

Comment: "... mes principaux qualités et défauts" sont grammaticalement corrects, mais à ne *jamais* employer. J'ai annulé ma correction, car il faudrait écrire, pour que cela soit correct dans une conversation : "... mes principales qualités, et aussi mes défauts principaux"

Comment: @cl-r mais pourriez-vous me communiquer une référence pour étayer ce que vous venez de dire? Merci d'avance

Comment: Phonétiquement on accorde l'adjectif avec le mot le plus proche, donc, l'oreille attend un masculin après 'principaux', et vous n'entendrez jamais dans une conversation la phrase que vous citez. En revanche, on peut aussi écrire "... mes qualités et défauts principaux." ; mais si l'on ne s'intéresse qu'à un petit nombre de qualités ET de défauts, on peut répéter l'adjectif une fois au féminin, une autre au masculin. C'est une question d'usage et de contexte, non de grammaire.

Comment: Je comprends ce que vous voulez dire, merci monsieur. @cl-r

Comment: Je suis francophone et je ne connais pas les règles de grammaire (il faut que je réfléchisse longtemps pour les retrouver) ; en revanche j'ai un certain nombre d'exemples, de phrases, de locutions qui me permettent de retrouver et de vérifier immédiatement la règle de grammaire. Au lycée j'ai appris l'anglais à partir de la grammaire... et je suis incapable de parler (à part l'*airport-english*), mais je peux le lire. C'est pour cela que votre question est intéressante, car elle interroge l'usage, je vous encourage à lire en français régulièrement et de le parler dès que l'occasion se présente

Answer (score 1):

"quality" can be a positive thing or just a characteristics, but
indeed this double meaning in French is exactly the same in English !
see:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quality
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quality